# ¿como activar un boton al llenar dos textbox en un webform?

Tags: c#, asp.net

He probado este código pero no me funciona, parece que solo sirve para Winforms:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Mnip.Enabled = false; //BOTON DESHABILITADO
}

private void clave1_TextLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if ((clave1.Text != "") && (clave2.Text != "")) Mnip.Enabled = true;
     else Mnip.Enabled = false;
}
private void clave2_TextLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if ((clave2.Text != "") && (clave1.Text != "")) Mnip.Enabled = true;
     else Mnip.Enabled = false;
}
```

Alguna idea de cómo hacerlo?

Así es como tengo los `TextBox`:

```
<asp:textbox TextMode = "Password" id="clave1" maxlength="4" minlength="4" placeholder="NUEVO NIP" runat="server" autocomplete="off></asp:textbox>

<asp:textbox TextMode = "Password" id="clave1" maxlength="4" minlength="4" placeholder="CONFIRMAR NIP" runat="server" autocomplete="off></asp:textbox>
```

Y el botón:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" name="Mnip" id= "Mnip" data-toggle="modal" disabled=false data-target="#nnm" class="btn btn-primary nav-link" text="CONFIRMAR"></asp:Button>
```

De hecho al presionar el botón me debe abrir un modal

```
<!--VENTANA MODAL-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="nnm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="nmlLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="form-group">
           <div class="modal-body">
           <h1>NIP GUARDADO CON EXITO
            <asp:Button id= "ConfNIP" runat = "server"  OnClick="ConfNIP_Click" data-toggle="modal" cssclass="btn btn-primary" style="font-size: 40px;
            font-family: Verdana,Helvetica; font-weight: bold;" Text="ACEPTAR"/></h1>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Y al presionar el botón `Aceptar` del modal se debe cerrar la sesión. Este formulario es para cambiar la contraseña.

Comment: Prueba con el evento `TextChanged`. Si no recuerdo mal asp.net no tiene evento `TextLeave`

Comment: Como dice @Pikoh utiliza otro evento, adicionalmente debería meter los textbox en un update panel

Comment: @LuisCarlosDonadoAvella yo no suelo programar asp.net, pero si no me equivoco se puede activar el `AutoPostback` del `Textbox` no?

Comment: he usado el TextChanged y pasa lo mismo :c

Comment: @sunflower primero debes activar el `AutoPostback` de los textboxes para que al abandonarles se dispare el evento, y por otro lado debes enlazar cada textbox con el manejador. Puedes pulsar en [edit]  y pegar la definicion de esos dos textboxes?

Comment: @pikoh lo del update panel es para no tener que refrescar la pagina por completo, pero se puede hacer sin el obviamente

Comment: @Pikoh a que te refieres con enlazar cada textbox con el manejador?? y el autopostback lo que hace es borrarme lo que escriboen cuanto paso al siguiente textbox y eso no es lo que necesito

Comment: En ese caso creo que lo que tienes que hacer es meter los dos TextBox en un UpdatePanel, para que no haga Postback, y para enlazar con el método debes añadir `ontextchanged` apuntando al método: `<asp:textbox TextMode = "Password" id="clave1" maxlength="4" minlength="4" placeholder="CONFIRMAR NIP" runat="server" autocomplete="off ontextchanged="clave2_TextChanged"></asp:textbox>`